# AWS Kinesis Data Firehose: Authentication token using a custom HTTP header (or any workaround)

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want to take advantage of AWS Kinesis Data Firehose with a destination of HTTP endpoint to stream text. The destination expects for authentication an HTTP header of the form:
Authentication: Bearer xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
No other format is allowed, and no, I cannot control that.

After doing some testing, I couldn't find a way to have a successful setup :(
The problem is it seems there is no way for me to customize the access key header or to add another header as per my requirement. This is how KDF sends the headers (I added mine in the forth position if you notice) :

```
"headers": {
        "content-length": "1286",
        "x-amzn-tls-version": "TLSv1.2",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
#this   "x-amz-firehose-common-attributes": "{\"commonAttributes\":{\"Authorization\":\"Bearer: xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx\"}}",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-for": "13.100.100.100",
        "x-amzn-tls-cipher-suite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "x-amz-firehose-request-id": "xxxxxx-ab4f-4771-a3bf-xxxxxxxx",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-xxxx-5f4c2f236809bxxxxxxxx",
#this   "x-amz-firehose-access-key": "xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
        ....
}
```

Am I missing any alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Kinesis Firehose with a HTTP endpoint destination, the authentication with datadog API works when adding `?dd-protocol=aws-kinesis-firehose` in the URL:
`https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/api/v2/logs?dd-protocol=aws-kinesis-firehose`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).